# How to turn 'Detections' object into string

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision

I have this code which uses YOLOV5 and the weights of my trained model for inferencing images to detect and recognize the Egyptian currency. The object 'results' is of datatype 'Detections'. Is there someway to convert it into a string object as I need the label output for some purpose? I tried the str() function but it didn't work.

```
import torch
import os
import cv2

# Model
model = torch.hub.load(r'C:\Users\HAYA\PycharmProjects\curency_recognition\yolov5-master\yolov5-master', 'custom', path=r'C:\Users\HAYA\PycharmProjects\curency_recognition\_best.pt', source='local')
# Image
im = [r'E:\_currency.jpg']
# Inference
results = model(im)
# results
results.print()
results.save()  # or .show()
results.show()
results.xyxy[0]  # img1 predictions (tensor)
results.pandas().xyxy[0]
```

Comment: Why didn't `str()` work?

Comment: I tried to print its output and compare it to the 'results' object and it obviously seemed that it didn't work

Comment: So you mean that when the line with `str()` was executed the code crashed and there was an error message saying that `str(Detection)` is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function is kind of "buggy" but it can give you the required results

```
def results_parser(results):
  s = ""
  if results.pred[0].shape[0]:
    for c in results.pred[0][:, -1].unique():
      n = (results.pred[0][:, -1] == c).sum()  # detections per class
      s += f"{n} {results.names[int(c)]}{'s' * (n > 1)}, "  # add to string
  return s
```

I run the default yolov5s on Zidane image from the original repository, after getting results object I did the following:

```
# Model
model = torch.hub.load(r'/content/yolov5//', 'custom', path=r'/content/yolov5/yolov5s.pt', source='local')
# Image
im = [r'runs/detect/exp/zidane.jpg']
# Inference
results = model(im)
print(results_parser(results))
```

and the output is:

```
2 persons, 2 ties,
```

I wish you find this answer helpful, have a good day)